# AEM startup issue

Tags: content-management-system, aem, jackrabbit, crx

While starting AEM author, it gives the following error:

> *WARN* [FelixStartLevel] org.apache.jackrabbit.core.util.RepositoryLock Existing lock file C:\CQ5\AEM-author\crx-quickstart\repository.lock detected. Repository was not shut down properly.

Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Hi Mike - can you describe what you've tried so far in resolving the problem with the lock file, what seems to have worked and what hasn't worked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't indicate which version of AEM you are using but I think the CRX 2.3 troubleshooting info at https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/crx/2-3/administering/repository_lock.html is valid for all versions that run on CRX.

Answer (score 0):

Stop your instance, In your `C:\CQ5\AEM-author\crx-quickstart\` search for all `.lock` files and delete them and restart.